Prevent iOS browser to enable full screen camera mode when streaming camera video
I have worked through this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia to capture video streams from a Front or Rear camera on an iPhone.
When testing the website on my desktop browser, everything works as expected but when testing it on my iPhone with Safari or Edge it shows the camera feed in full screen mode and not in the grey video box.
Website can be tested here: https://codepen.io/chrisbeast/pen/ebYwpX
feather.replace();

const controls = document.querySelector('.controls');
const cameraOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options>select');
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const screenshotImage = document.querySelector('img');
const buttons = [...controls.querySelectorAll('button')];
let streamStarted = false;

const [play, pause, screenshot] = buttons;

const constraints = {
  video: {
    width: {
      min: 1280,
      ideal: 1920,
      max: 2560,
    },
    height: {
      min: 720,
      ideal: 1080,
      max: 1440
    },
  }
};

cameraOptions.onchange = () => {
  const updatedConstraints = {
    ...constraints,
    deviceId: {
      exact: cameraOptions.value
    }
  };

  startStream(updatedConstraints);
};

play.onclick = () => {
  if (streamStarted) {
    video.play();
    play.classList.add('d-none');
    pause.classList.remove('d-none');
    return;
  }
  if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    const updatedConstraints = {
      ...constraints,
      deviceId: {
        exact: cameraOptions.value
      }
    };
    startStream(updatedConstraints);
  }
};

const pauseStream = () => {
  video.pause();
  play.classList.remove('d-none');
  pause.classList.add('d-none');
};

const doScreenshot = () => {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  screenshotImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
  screenshotImage.classList.remove('d-none');
};

pause.onclick = pauseStream;
screenshot.onclick = doScreenshot;

const startStream = async (constraints) => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  handleStream(stream);
};


const handleStream = (stream) => {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  play.classList.add('d-none');
  pause.classList.remove('d-none');
  screenshot.classList.remove('d-none');

};


const getCameraSelection = async () => {
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
  const options = videoDevices.map(videoDevice => {
    return `<option value="${videoDevice.deviceId}">${videoDevice.label}</option>`;
  });
  cameraOptions.innerHTML = options.join('');
};

getCameraSelection();


Adding playsinline attribute will instructs the browser to play the video inline within the document context, rather than automatically using fullscreen mode.
You can add it directly to your HTML, like
<video autoplay playsinline></video>

To learn more about playsinline you can read this article

ah... close! I had  and that did not work :D Thanks!
In the end I solved it using



that allows to capture the picture properly and brings up the usual controls a user would expect

@MaxB, happy that you could figure out a solution.
